# Unable to run zerorpc on Node js after installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, failed-installation

I am attempting to setup `zerorpc` with Node.js. However, even after installing `zerorpc`, I get the error:

```
Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

Here is the code from my `.js` file:

```
var zerorpc = require("zerorpc");

var client = new zerorpc.Client();
client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");

client.invoke("hello", "World!", function(error, res, more) {
   console.log(res);
});
```

I installed `zerorpc` with this series of commands:

```
brew install zmq

npm install zerorpc
```

It appears that zerorpc has installed correctly, as I see a folder with all the files that are supposed to be included with the `zerorpc` package. However, I do not understand the root of the error. Could someone explain why this error is occuring?

Comment: I suspect you have some problem with your nodejs installation. This error is unrelated to zerorpc.

Comment: Ref.: **`Exception: ..  Can't find variable: require`** -- obviously not a ZeroMQ problem, check how can that happen, that the syntax **`require( <package> )`** was rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions. I had to run the `.js` file as `node filename.js` rather than `js filename.js`.